# Get nearest geometry in spatiality using spatial index

Tags: geometry, spatial, spatialite

I'd like to get the nearest feature to a given point in Spatialite using a spatial SQL query. I'd like to speed it up using index table. Spatial index boundary should be calculated from defined point and a given tolerance, all features that are totally/partly within rtree bounding box should be used in the query.

I have tried several way, but I had always **problem with spatial index boundary**.

Like this:

SELECT *, Distance(GeomFromText('POINT(19.02658 47.51574)'),mo_utak_polyline.Geometry) as distance FROM mo_utak_polyline WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT pkid FROM idx_mo_utak_polyline_Geometry WHERE xmin > 19.01408 AND xmax < 19.03908 AND ymin > 47.50324 AND ymax < 47.52824) AND distance <=0.0025) ORDER by distance

Or this:

SELECT *,Intersects(GeomFromText('POINT(19.02658 47.51574)'), megyehatar_region.Geometry) as intersects FROM megyehatar_region WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT pkid FROM idx_megyehatar_region_Geometry WHERE xmin > 14.02658 AND xmax < 24.02658 AND ymin > 42.51574 AND ymax < 52.51574) AND intersects=1

**I can always get features that are totally contained by my index defined bounding box.** It causes a huge problem for me, e.g. when I try to query line features, when their length is totally different, it can be 1 cm or even 1000 km, so it is hard to set **the size of spatial index bounding box**.

Which do you think the best way to do it?

How to change this part of the query

SELECT pkid FROM idx_mo_utak_polyline_Geometry WHERE xmin > 19.01408 AND xmax < 19.03908 AND ymin > 47.50324 AND ymax < 47.52824)

to return not only the features that are contained by the bounding box, but also those intersects with it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM idx_mo_utak_polyline_Geometry WHERE 
MBRContains(BuildMBR('19.01408','47.50324' , '19.03908', '47.52824'), BuildMBR(xmin,ymin , xmax, ymax)) OR
MBRIntersects(BuildMBR('19.01408','47.50324' , '19.03908', '47.52824'), BuildMBR(xmin,ymin , xmax, ymax))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make first query to index, than you can do ***intersects***, and, even better, ***distance == 0*** to the geometries you've got from indexed query:

Your point coordinates - X,Y

```
    SELECT * FROM table 
        WHERE pk_uid IN (SELECT pkid FROM idx_table_geometry 
                         WHERE xmin < X AND ymin < Y AND xmax > X AND ymax > Y) 
              AND distance( makepoint(X,Y), geometry ) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit old (in the meantime, handling of spatial index seems to have changed a bit in spatialite), but here's what I have come up with in my project just now (year 2015). The query is supposed to take each point from a pointlayer and find the closest line from a line layer.

I'm not sure how well structured this code is and how fast it will compute against a large dataset (my test-set is small).

I'm highly interested in getting feedback, if you see improvement in this query (my sql is very rusty – it's been a while...)

```
select * 
from pointlayer as p
left join linelayer as l on
    Distance(p.geometry, l.geometry) in (
       select MIN(Distance(p.geometry, geometry)) 
       from linelayer
       where pk in (
           select rowid
           from SpatialIndex
           where f_table_name = 'linelayer'
           and search_frame = BuildCircleMbr(X(b.geometry), Y(b.geometry),25))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In SpatiaLite version 4.4 or greater there is now a KNN (K-Nearest Neighbors) index that works quite well. I recently wrote a query that for each of about 500 points looked for the nearest linestring from 5 million line records. Using the newer VirtualSpatialIndex method mentioned by KaeptnHaddock the query ran for about 3 minutes. With the new KNN index the query took less than 20 seconds. Here is my KNN query:

```
select k.* from knn k, points p
WHERE f_table_name = 'linestrings' 
AND ref_geometry = p.geometry
AND max_items = 1;
```